# How to send data from fragment to deep nested component?

Tags: graphql, relay, relaymodern

I'm working with Relay Modern on Project. But I'm not sure how to send data from a place when I put fragment
to place where Is component placed.

for example:

this is components composition

```
-Page (QueryRenderer)
---Header
---body
  ---List
     --UserAutocomplete
```

List is Fragment, something like  `fragment PaymentsList on Payment`
UserAutocomplete is also fragment but on RootQuery `fragment UserAutocomplete_users on RootQuery`

Actually, I put  bout this fragment in query for QueryRenderer

`` graphql`
  query PaymentQuery {
    ...PaymentsList
    ...UserAutocompleteFragment_users
  } ``

But then I got data for UserAutocomplete here and I must send this data for UserAtocomplete component down through props.
  Is there some better way something like got this data from a store instead of sending them through props?

Comment: I have the same problem! I really want to be able to easily pass data through a component that is grouping a bunch of other components. The data isn't nested, it's flat. Not sure the best way to pass data through a parent component

Comment: I wonder why they didn't took Redux's connect example. The container should be something similar so instead of passing data down through props you get them directly from containers

Comment: First thing you get taught when learning Relay its that you should be able to work inside a component without need to know whats going on other containers, isn't Relay clever enough to pass you the properties from the top container to the bottom one directly?

Comment: Maybe there is an undocumented mechanism. Anyway, I wrote a proposal in https://github.com/facebook/relay/issues/2305, which at the end addresses this question